# Finding subsequences of vector from a vector of structs

Tags: c++, vector, struct

I'm trying to find subsequences of vector from a larger vector.

Here's my full code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct Elem {

    bool isString;
    float f;
    string s;
};

void getFounds(vector<Elem> &src, vector<Elem> &dst, vector<size_t> &founds)
{
    //what should be in here?
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    vector<Elem> elems1 = {{false, 1.f, ""}, {false, 2.f, ""}, {true, 0.f, "foo"},
                           {false, 1.f, ""}, {false, 2.f, ""}, {true, 0.f, "foo"}}; //the source vector
    vector<Elem> elems2 = {{false, 2.f, ""}, {true, 0.f, "foo"}}; //the subsequence to find
    vector<size_t> founds; //positions found

    getFounds(elems1, elems2, founds);

    for (size_t i=0; i<founds.size(); ++i)
        cout << founds[i] << endl; // should print 1, 4

    return 0;
}
```

I could do this with `std::search` if I use it for vector of single types but if I use it for vector of structs, it shows an error saying

> "invalid operands to binary expression ('const Elem' and 'const
>   Elem')"

Is it really impossible to use `std::search` in this case?
What would be the good way to implement `getFounds()` in the code?

**EDIT : I could make it work by creating an `operator` function and using `std::search`**

```
bool operator==(Elem const& a, Elem const& b)
{
    return a.isString == b.isString && a.f == b.f && a.s == b.s;
}

void getFounds(vector<Elem> &src, vector<Elem> &dst, vector<size_t> &founds)
{
    for (size_t i=0; i<src.size(); ++i) {

        auto it = search(src.begin()+i, src.end(), dst.begin(), dst.end());

        if (it != src.end()) {

            size_t pos = distance(src.begin(), it);
            founds.push_back(pos);
            i += pos;
        }
    }
}
```

However, I would appreciate if anyone can give me an advice to make the code simpler.

Comment: Maybe define `operator==` for `Elem`

Comment: `//what should be in here?`: Whatever you want.

Comment: @M.M Can you show me an example how to?

Comment: @ZackLee Is how to define such an operator your actual question?

Comment: @BaummitAugen As I wrote, I have 2 questions, 1) if it's impossible to use std::search. 2) What would be the good way to implement getFounds() in the code. "How to define an operator" is related to the first one.

Comment: make a free function `void operator==(Elem const& a, Elem const& b);` , include logic so that it returns `true` if they are equal and `false` otherwise

Comment: @M.M I'm sorry how can a void function return a value?

Comment: @ZackLee, can you actually post your non-working attempt which gives you the error with structs and works fine with what you call "single types", rather than asking to implement getFounds(...) in an arbitrary way? If you will have troubles with defining operator== for the structs as M.M. suggested, that is what you should ask about. Your getFounds is not == at all.

Comment: Er, I mean `bool` sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it really impossible to use `std::search` in this case?

No, you just need to implement the `operator==` function in your `struct` as you've done. You could also implement the `operator!=` as well, example:

```
struct Elem
{
    bool isString;
    float f;
    std::string s;

    bool operator==(const Elem& other) const {
        return (this->isString == other.isString &&
                this->f == other.f &&
                this->s == other.s);
    }

    bool operator!=(const Elem& other) const {
        return !(*this == other);
    }
};
```

> What would be the good way to implement `getFounds()` in the code? ... advice to make it simpler.

Simpler is relative, especially since you're already using the standard library to achieve what you want; however, you could also implement the `getFounds` function like so:

```
void getFounds(const std::vector<Elem>& src, const std::vector<Elem>& sub, std::vector<size_t>& founds)
{
    size_t count = 0, tot = 0;
    auto beg = sub.begin();
    for (auto look = src.begin(); look != src.end();) {
        if (*look != *beg) { ++look; ++count; continue; }
        for (tot = 0; beg != sub.end(); ++beg, ++look, ++tot) {
            if (look == src.end()) { break; }
            if (*look != *beg) { break; }
        }
        if (tot == sub.size()) { founds.push_back(count); }
        count += tot;
        beg = sub.begin();
    }
}
```

I don't know if that's "simpler" for your needs, as it does essentially what the [`std::search`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/search) algorithm would do (loop and check and break if elements aren't matching, etc.), it's just "another" way to do it.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I just measured CPU time just for fun and here's a result.
When I run getFounds() 1M times, 
1) Using std::search took about 0.39 seconds.
2) Using your code took about 0.45 seconds. :)

Answer (score 1):

Override == and iterate through both arrays looking for match:

```
bool operator==(Elem const &el1, Elem const &el2)
{
    return 
        el1.isString == el2.isString 
        && 
        el1.f == el2.f 
        && 
        el1.s == el2.s;
}

void getFounds(std::vector<Elem> const &src, std::vector<Elem> const &dst, std::vector<size_t> &founds)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < src.size(); ++i)
        for (size_t j = 0; j < dst.size(); ++j)
            if (src[i] == dst[j])
                founds.push_back(i);
}
```

This however will find every index. For example your example will print 1 2 4 5. If you want to abort after 1st find, you need to add some additional logic to it.